# Calculate video total video length and output as total with respective folder

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, find

I'm working with some videos and I want to measure the total length of videos each folder contains and output it with the respective folder. Current structure is like this.

```
.
└── Parent folder/
    ├── Trip 1/
    │   ├── Video 1
    │   └── Video 2
    ├── Trip 2/
    │   ├── Video 3
    │   └── Video 4
    └── Trip 3/
        ├── Video 5
        └── Video 6
```

The output I'm trying to get is like this

```
Parent folder
  Trip 1 3h34m
  Trip 2 5h14m
  Trip 3 8h12m
```

So far I was able to get total of all 3 sub folders but I couldn't get it right to show it folder basis.

```
mediainfo '--Output=Video;%Duration%\n' *.mp4 | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { secs=sum/1000; h=int(secs/3600);m=int((secs-h*3600)/60);s=int(secs-h*3600-m*60); printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n",h,m,s) }'
```

I'm open to use mediainfo or ffprobe packages or anything you suggest.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: @user68186 I'm using Ubuntu 22.0. Thank you!

Comment: @user68186 how is this question related to the Ubuntu version - so why ask?

Comment: @ArturMeinild I wanted to know that OP is using one of the official flavors of Ubuntu that have not reached the End of Life (EOL) so that the question is on topic. There is [another stack exchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) for generic Linux questions where such questions are welcome even for Debian, Mint or a very old versions of Ubuntu. General Linux questions are fine here as long as you are using a currently supported version of Ubuntu or its official flavors.

Comment: @user68186 what does it matter if the question is version agnostic? It almost seems if you're looking for a reason to close questions..

Answer (score 0):

Your method is sound, you just need to nest it per folder.

```bash
find . -type d |while IFS= read dir; do
  t=$(mediainfo '--Output=Video;%Duration%\n' "$dir"/*.mp4 | awk '
    { sum += $1 }
    END {
      secs = int(sum / 1000 + 0.5);
      h = int(secs / 3600);
      m = int((secs - h * 3600) / 60);
      s = int(secs - h * 3600 - m * 60);
      printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", h, m, s)
    }') 2>/dev/null
  if [ "$t" != "00:00:00" ]; then
    echo "$dir: $t"
  fi
done \
  |sed -r 's:[^/]*/:--/:g; s:((--/)*)--/:\1-- :; s:--/:|   :g; s:([| ]*)-:\1|-:'
```

To adapt this to output hours and minutes as you requested in the question, change the `printf` statement to say `printf "%dh%02.0fm", h, m + s/60` (this also rounds to the nearest minute).

I assume you already understand the `mediainfo` and `awk` commands since you supplied them, though I did change the millisecond conversion to be rounded. I've merely wrapped this in a `find` call that looks at all children directories of the current path (change `.` for another path) and loops through its output line by line (`while IFS= read dir` will read each line, even if there is spacing in it, into `$dir`. This will not work if you have linebreaks in your directory names).

Since the directory might not contain any .mp4 files, I've piped errors from the assignment to `$t` to /dev/null and then run a test to ensure the time isn't `00:00:00` (change that to `0h00m` if you adapted the output). Then I print the directory and the time.

Finally, a `sed` uses extended regular expressions (`-r`) to convert this into a tree with four substitutions (`s`):

1. Convert each parent directory name to two dashes (keep the trailing slash for now)
2. Remove the final trailing slash
3. Any parent remaining should get a pipe and spaces
4. Add interim pipes